# Smalltalk syntax error

Tags: smalltalk

I'm learning smalltalk right now and am trying to make a very simple program that creates an array of numbers and then finds the largest number. My code looks like this:

```
| list max |
list := #(1 8 4 5 3).
    1 to: list size do: [:i |
    max < (list at: i)
        ifTrue: [max := (list at: i)].
        ifFalse: [max := max].
    ].
```

When I run this code, I get "stdin:7: parse error, expected ']'". I'm a bit confused as to what is causing this. It looks to me like all of my square brackets correspond. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *immediate* problem is that you terminate the `ifTrue` section with a period. You could normally just remove the period but, since your `ifFalse` section is effectively a non-operation, it's probably better to remove that bit.

But even when you fix that, you still need to initialise `max` so that you don't get a `<`  message being sent to the `nil` object. You can initialise it to the first element, if there are any, then you can change the loop to start at the second.

Of course, initialising to the first element is problematic when the list is empty so you should handle that as well. In the code below, I've set it to a suitable small value then initialised it from the first element of the list only if it's available.

Corrected code is:

```
| list max |
list := #(1 8 4 5 3).
max := -99999.
(list size) > 0 ifTrue: [max := (list at: 1)].
2 to: list size do: [:i |
    max < (list at: i) ifTrue: [max := (list at: i)].
]
(max) displayNl
```

This outputs `8` as expected and also works fine on the edge cases (list size of zero and one).

Comment: I modified your code a little bit and got it to work. We only need it to work on the explicit array that we create, so I got rid of the size checks. Thanks!

Comment: I might be being pedantic here, but beware of hard-coding presumed max or min values (consider the list `#(-100001 -100002)`). Safer to use a `nil` check in the loop or better yet, simply return nil for the empty list base case.

Comment: The presumed max only comes into play for an empty list. For a non-empty list, the line following the `-99999` assignment sets the max value to a real one (the first element in the list).

Answer (score 5):

Alexandre told you already that is likely that collection provides a max method. You might be interested in a few ways how to do it.

Using collection max (maximum of all elements)

```
#(1 8 4 5 3) max
```

Using number max: (which of two numbers is bigger)

```
#(1 8 4 5 3) inject: 0 into: [:max :elem|
     max max: elem ]
```

Or using just using the internal iterator

```
#(1 8 4 5 3) inject: 0 into: [:max :elem|
    max < elem 
       ifTrue: [ elem ]
       ifFalse:[ max ] ]
```

Together with your solution to use an external iteration you can see there are a lot of possibilities.

Hope it adds something

Comment: Yet another alternative is to use fold:. Works as long as you can guarantee your list isn't empty: `#(1 8 4 5 3) fold: [:a :b | a max: b]`

Comment: I was thinking about fold as well but I thought that's enough examples. And inject:into: works reliably.

Comment: +1 from me, no need to re-invent the wheel (unless perhaps it's meant as a programming exercise).

Answer (score 4):

The line number seems off but looking at your code it seems the error is probably caused by the period after `ifTrue: [max := (list at: i)]`. `#ifTrue:ifFalse` is a single method selector and it doesn't make sense to break it into two statements.

Actually you could remove the `ifFalse` part of the code entirely. Assigning max to itself has no effect. Also looping on the indices is not needed here. You can work on the values directly with `list do: […]`.

The max variable should also be initialized. Zero seems like a good choice to compare against the positive numbers in your array.

But instead of doing all that look into the Collection class. Your Smalltalk dialect may already offer a `max` method for this task.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would've used something already built in, but it is a homework assignment, so we have to re-invent the wheel.